# Recover code repository in Github?

Tags: github, repository, recover

I recently inherited a project that used to be setup with Github for version control. However, due to lack of communication from the original developer, I'm left with code base that lives on the production. Question I have is if it's possible to recover a code repo in Github given that I have the `.git` folder that contains all git related files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's an existing `.git` folder, it's probably an existing git repository. You could just follow the instructions for [adding an existing project to Github](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/) and get it that way.

Comment: Thanks @waynnl! Since the original repo was created and owned by the original dev who had his own Github account, given that i only have what's in .git folder, do you know if there should be some sort of handoff (possibly required by Github) between me and the original dev in order for me to fully own the whole repo and all future control?

Comment: You can push to your own repo that you can control, and invite whichever collaborators you want.