# How do I pull my code from a different but added repo on Github

Tags: git, github, virtual-machine

So I have been working on a project with my partners and now I still got some tests to run, however I did the coding on my friend's laptop and now my own VM did not add the Repository that we worked on. That is to say I have my own repo added in VM but unable to access the other one where we pushed our code. Can someone give me a quick guide on how to pull my code from that repo? (Except download them and rebuild them all over again...)

Comment: Does this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857268/recover-code-repository-in-github) ask a similar question? If so, it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I did a bit research after and found out this link from Github team which provides some detailed guides, still anyone else's help will be appreciated!

https://help.github.com/articles/fetching-a-remote/